# SSIS - add headers two different output files

Tags: sql-server, ssis, header, etl, flat-file

I have a package that has two different flat files for output. 
How can I add different headers to each one, using the corresponding variables?

Comment: What do you mean by headers?

Comment: Specific text at the top line of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that at Data Flow's properties I can add expressions, that give the option to add header directly to each destination file.

Comment: You have to accept this answer even if it is yours, click on the mark below the voting arrows

Comment: Thank you, I will be able to do so by tomorrow